# Ruby on Rails, Highcharts, Chart Labels (Dynamic) Issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, highcharts

I am trying to get dynamic labels to show properly on pie charts using Highcharts and RoR:

View: dashboard.html.erb

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: "#FFBF00",
      renderTo: "notes_alt",
      type: "pie"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Notes By Subject Type in Percentage"
    },
    xAxis: {
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            categories: <%=raw @subject_types.to_json %>,
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "Notes",
        plotBackgroundColor: "#FFBF00",
        labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    categories: <%=raw @subject_types.to_json %>,
                }
            },
    },
    tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: <%=raw @subject_types.to_json %>
            },
    plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    plotBackgroundColor: "#FFBF00",
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format:'<b>{point.subject_type}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
    series: [{
     name: 's',
     data: <%= @dataWLabel %>
    }]
  });
 });
</script>
```

Note Controller:

```
    def dashboard
      @data = Note.getData()
      @dataWLabels = Note.getDataWithLabels()
      @subjects = Note.subject_types
    ...
    end
```

You can see the two approaches I am taking in the model.

Model (Note.rb):

```
def self.getData
    data = []
    self.subject_types.each do |type|
      data << self.type_count(type)
    end
    data
  end

def self.getDataWithLabels
    data = Hash.new
    self.subject_types.each do |type|
      data["a"] = self.type_count(type)
    end
    data
  end

....def self.subject_types
    pluck(:subject_type).uniq
  end

  def self.type_count(type)
    where(subject_type: type).count
  end
```

Neither work. The first (getData) prints a string in place of the label:

["Geography Class C","English","","History","Maths Class B","Maths C3"]

The second (getDataWithLabels) does not allow the chart to render at all. <%=raw @subect_types.to_json %> also prints a string.

I want each subject to appear on each slice (not a string of subjects on each slice):

[image: Pie chart]

Any ideas here? Thanks. Can add more info if needed.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you are trying to use `xAxis` and `yAxis` in a pie chart. There is no axis in the pie chart ;) That means everything should be set  in point options, for example: `[ [name, value], [name, value], ... , [name, value] ]`. Where `name` is your `subject_type`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused with the syntax - how do I put this in to the code? [<%= raw @subject_type.to_json %>, value]?? - should I include "raw" here? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a ruby dev, so I don't know the details, but in general, you should combine two arrays, so in the result you will have one array where each of the objects will be another array. I can show you how to do it in JS, though.